# Delete Entire Rows which do not have certain Text in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete the entire rows that do not have "AB" or "ON" in ID field in column A. I have written the code below but it deletes all the rows. Can anyone assist me with this please. I have attached the screenshot of the data, Thanks! [Data Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BISij.jpg):

```
Sub DeleteRows()

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

Do While i <= FinalRow

    If Cells(i, "A") <> "PQ*" OR If Cells(i, "A") <> "ON*" Then

        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete

        FinalRow = FinalRow - 1

    Else

        i = i + 1

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This is looking for exact matches on the strings and not using `*` as a wildcard if this is what you want then change your OR to an AND in your F Statement.  Otherwise more changes will need to be done look into Instr().

Comment: Hi Scott, changing OR to AND did not work. It is still deleting all the rows in the sheet

Comment: Then your problem is the second part of my comment you are trying to use a wildcard with `<>` which will not work.  Us LEFT() or Instr() in your If.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my Comments:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

Do While i <= FinalRow

    If Left(Cells(i, "A"), 2) = "PQ" Or Left(Cells(i, "A"), 2) = "ON" Then

        i = i + 1

    Else

        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete

        FinalRow = FinalRow - 1


    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! that works. Thanks a lot Scott for the help!

Answer (score 1):

- When deleting rows, you are better off going from the bottom up
- Wild cards cannot be used with the equality operators; you should be using the `Like`operator.
- Your logic is off a bit.  You need to enclose the `OR` in parentheses

If you are using the wild card as I understand it in your original post, it translates to cells that **start with** PQ or ON

So:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim I As Long

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For I = FinalRow To 2 Step -1
    If Not (Cells(I, "A") Like "PQ*" Or _
        Cells(I, "A") Like "AB*") Then _
        Cells(I, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that is more similar to what you were doing.

EDITED: Should work if the ID is the first two letters.

```
Sub Deleterows()

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row

i = 2

Do While i <= FinalRow

If Not Left(Cells(i, "A"), 2) = "PQ" And Not Left(Cells(i, "A"), 2) = "ON" Then

    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete

    FinalRow = FinalRow - 1

Else

    i = i + 1

End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi timthebomb, the problem with that is since my ID is in format AB0001, SK0002 etc, with the current if condition, it will not recognize the IDs having AB or ON but will delete all rows as there will not be exact match for AB or ON